# Average of Gaussian integers in a disk

Tags: number-theory

I'll denote the Gaussian integers by $G=\{n+im : n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit. My question deals with calculating the average value of all such numbers over a disk, particularly as the radius of that disk tends to infinity. Specifically, we select some center point $s\in\mathbb{C}$, and consider the following average as $R$ approaches infinity.
$$\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\sum_{p\in G}^{|p-s|<R}p$$

My question is about whether this expression converges as $R\to\infty$. I know that *if it does* converge, then it must converge to $s$, the disk's center, but I don't know if it converges or not. Is this a known problem? Is there any literature on the subject?

---

I have a few related results, which motivates my conjecture. As a trivial observation, the sum is constantly zero when $s=0$. This happens because we're always adding $p$ and $-p$ at the same time. By similar logic, even if $s\neq 0$, many terms near the origin will cancel out when $R$ is very large, and some analysis will prove that when $s$ stays bounded, likewise our expression is bounded across all $R>1$. Analyzing more carefully shows that the difference between the average and $s$ is globally bounded, across all $s\in\mathbb{C}$ and $R>1$. Furthermore, the average *of the average* converges to $s$ exactly, in the following sense.
$$s = \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1}{R}\int_1^R \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\sum_{p\in G}^{|p-s|<r}p\,dr$$

That the average hovers around $s$ isn't surprising, since the disk itself is centered at $s$, and the Gaussian integers are rather uniform. The difficulty is proving that the average actually converges to $s$, as opposed to some chaotic orbit. For comparison, if we used a grid-aligned square instead of a disk, the average actually doesn't converge for most $s$. Because the lattice is coordinated with the geometry of the square, we get large periodic variations that don't vanish in the limit.

Comment: The set of Gaussian integers is usually written $\mathbb Z[i]$.  Also,
$$\pi R^2 \sim \#\{p \in \mathbb Z[i] : |p - s| < R\},$$
so you really do only need to consider the average of the numbers within a given bound.